# Topos associated to a category

Tags: classifying-spaces, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, ct.category-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

For each topos $\mathbb E$ let $\mathcal O(\mathbb E)$ be the locally presentable category of objects in $\mathbb E$. We can make $\mathcal O$ into a contravariant functor to the category of locally presentable categories (with morphisms being cocontinuous) by assigning to each geometric morphism $(f^\*, f_\*)$ the functor $f^\*$. By [Mac Lane, Moerdijk: Sheaves in Geometry and Logic] this functor is representable, that is there is a topos $\mathbb A$, called the *object classifier*, such that there is a natural equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb E, \mathbb A) \to \mathcal O(\mathbb E).
$$ 
Now I wonder whether $\mathcal O$ has a right adjoint, which I want to call $\operatorname{Spec}$ due to the analogy with algebraic geometry, that is whether there exists a contravariant functor $\operatorname{Spec}$ from the category of locally presentable categories to the category of topoi (with geometric morphisms) such that there is a natural equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb E, \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal C) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal C, \mathcal O(\mathbb E))
$$
of categories.

(Here, *topos* shall mean *Grothendieck topos*.)

Comment: I guess you want to cut down to small categories C, in order to get a Spec(C) satisfying your requirements. When C is small, the theory of diagrams on C is a geometric theory, and therefore has a classifying topos Spec(C).  So (modulo the size question), I think the answer to your question must be yes. But I'll let others more expert than me answer.

Comment: You should be willing to change one of the $\mathrm{Hom}$ to something  else, such as "continuous functors". But I'll let others more expert than me answer.

Comment: I like your question. But I'll let others more expert than me answer.

Comment: @Tom: You are right; in my question I am a bit sloppy when it comes to size issues.

@Andrej: Do you possibly mean cocontinuous?

I will changed my question to address both comments in a manner that is hopefully helpful.

Comment: There is some hesitation between terminology continuous and cocontinuous. Bass used right and left continuous and right continuous was more important in module theory, so some retained continuous for what pure category theorists say cocontinuous. See also Lurie's book which also has it that way (and also Rosenberg who follows Bass).

Comment: I don't really get the analogy with algebraic geometry, except that we use the same symbols ($\mathbb{A}$, $\mathcal{O}$, $f^*$ ...). How strict is this analogy really?

Comment: PLease, let me know what is the "locally presentable category of objects in a topos E" (?)

Comment: @Sergio: If you have a topos, which is a category of a certain form, and you forget about that extra information, you are left with just a category, which I call the category of objects of the topos. It happens to be a locally presentable category [Francis Borceux: Handbook of Categorical Algebra: Categories of Sheaves (proposition 3.4.16)].

Comment: @Martin: For the moment, the analogy is just formal to me. For the topos that I write $\mathbb{A}$ Mac Lane and Moerdijk write $S[U]$ in analogy to a polynomial ring because the set of morphisms from the polynomial algebra over a ground ring to another algebra is just the set of elements of that other algebra as the category of morphisms from a topos to $S[U]$ is the category of objects of that topos. I doesn't like that notation too much as one has to turn arrows around so that one should introduce, at least formally, somewhere a $\operatorname{Spec}$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is described in the paper

> Bunge and Carboni, The symmetric topos, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra 105:233-249, 1995.

which describes the sense in which the construction you call Spec is analogous to the symmetric algebra construction.

Bunge and Carboni give a biadjunction between the bicategory R, which is the opposite of the bicategory of Grothendieck toposes, and the bicategory A of locally presentable categories and cocontinuous functors (equivalently, left adjoints).